# Foreign key and primary key relation in mongodb node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm using node js with mongoDb as database. i have created 2 schema name subject and classroom with different id's. in 3rd schema name timetable i want those id in first two schema to become foreign key in timetable schema. it is possible in Mongodb?

**Subject Schema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var shortid = require('shortid');


var SubjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({

    subject_id: {

        required: true, 
        'type': String,
        'default': shortid.generate
    },

    subject_name: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },

    subject_darjah:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    }

});

var Subject = mongoose.model('Subject', SubjectSchema);
module.exports = Subject;
```

**Classroom Schema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var shortid = require('shortid');


var ClassroomSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({

    classroom_id: {

        required: true, 
        'type': String,
        'default': shortid.generate
    },

    classroom_name: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },

    classroom_blok:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },

    classroom_floor: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },




});

var Classroom = mongoose.model('Classroom', ClassroomSchema);
module.exports = Classroom;
```

**TimeTable Schema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var shortid = require('shortid');

var TimetableSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({

    timeslot_id: {
        required: true, 
        'type': String,
        'default': shortid.generate
    },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a concept of reference in MongoDB please check official document for more.
And you need not have your own id fields. MongoDB adds auto-generated unique _id filed in all the documents.

it is something like this:

```
timeslotRef: {
   type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: "TimeSlot",
   required: true, 
},
```

reference [link](https://intellipaat.com/community/42080/referencing-another-schema-in-mongoose)